# Recommended Wallaby.js alternatives?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, wallaby.js

I'm trying to find a Wallaby.js alternative. I'd like to see test results "on the fly" (in VScode or Webstorm), Preferably, a free or at least a cheaper alternative. Searched google and could not find any. Any recommendations ?